# Is the time needed to reorganize the indexes on a table bounded above by the time that it takes to repopulate from scratch?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, benchmarking, reorganize

Under the very wrong assumption that it wouldn't take long, I've ran `ALTER INDEX ALL ON OUR_BIGGEST_TABLE REORGANIZE;`. 3 and a half hours later, it's not finished. From cruel experience, I know that I can repopulate that table from scratch (i.e. from truncation) in 7 hours. Presumably, truncation and re-population also refreshes the indexes. Does this mean that my `REORGANIZE` is extremely unlikely to take more than 7 hours?

Comment: I guess in about 3 hours you can let us know.

Comment: @Stu Sure, but I'd like to know what the theory says.

Comment: @Stu Well, for the record, it finished after 4 and a half hours.

Comment: I would summise then the answer is "yes", it *is* extremely unlikely to take more than 7 hours. Index reorg afaik only touches the leaf levels of the index so does less work than a rebuild.

Comment: FYI - reorganize is not a good option to use unless there is absolutely no other option available.  Rebuilding the index is going to perform much better - either ONLINE or OFFLINE and will rebuild based on the fill factor defined for the table.